# DateTime.ParseExact with format string returns weird value

Tags: c#

I try to parse a date providing a specified format with the following code :

```
    var date = "30/06/2014";
    var ret2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/mm/yyyy", null);
    var ret3 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    var ret4 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(ret2);
    Console.WriteLine(ret3);
    Console.WriteLine(ret4);

-----OUTPUT-----
30/01/2014 00:06:00
30/01/2014 00:06:00
30/01/2014 00:06:00
```

Could someone explain me why this code doesn't return the `30/06/2014 00:00:00` value I am expecting ?

Comment: MM is month, mm is minutes

Comment: Next time try [reading the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mm` is the placeholder for minutes. You should use `MM` for months

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid. Thank you :) I'll accept the answer in 11minutes.

Answer (score 2):

`mm` means minutes, not months. Try using `MM` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `mm` represents Minutes - note that the minutes of each DateTime is `06:00` instead of the default `00:00`, and `1` is the default for a month(since there is no `0` month).

See MSDN on [Standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) DateTime format strings for more info, as well as more helpful placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

the code used the wrong format string

```
var ret2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/mm/yyyy", null);
var ret3 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var ret4 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

mm is placeholder for minutes.
to get month, use MM in the format string

```
var ret2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
var ret3 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var ret4 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

check out the example on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx